# Reportlab printing defaults

Tags: python, printing, reportlab

I am using reportlab to create a pdf with some portait and some landscape pages.  The pdf looks great on screen, but when printing it the default print settings are to shrink the pages, rather than rotate them.  At first I though that this was just something to do with the settings, but a few other people have commented on it, using a variety of pdf readers and printers.  After a bit of investigating it seems that this is something to do with an option set inside the pdf itself, recommending those print settings. Does anyone know of a way to change this when the pdf is generated?

Comment: I don't believe you can do this with reportlab, but you should be able to edit the pdf document directly to change this setting if you can figure out what it is.

Comment: @GordonWorley Thanks.  I assume you mean edit the binary data on the pdf? Sounds complicated, but I'll look into it.  I would need to automate it since I'm generating a 1000s of them.

Comment: Its actually not too hard: pdf is actually a text format that you can edit pretty easily, save for some binary blobs related to features like security.

Comment: @GordonWorley Thanks for the info, I didn't realise it was that easy!  Just been looking at it and it seems that once I've figured out which setting I need to change, I can write a simple script to insert the text.